# Select All Checkbox from MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

Today I'm currently using "`Checkbox`" and just a little problem. I have a dropdown list in my first page, I choose the items "DropDown 1" and then I click the Submit button after that it will go to the next page. So then, the second page will load all items under the "DropDown 1" using a checkbox only.

My problem is:

How can I check them all by using a checkbox "Check All", where the items in "DropwDown 1" are came from my database [MySQL].

Here's my code in page two:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all" /> <label for='all'>All</label>
<?php
$dropdown_value = (string)$_POST["id"];
echo "<br/>";
if ($dropdown_value == 'All Building') 
{

     $all = mysql_query("SELECT fldBldgName FROM tblbuildings");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($all))
           {
                echo "<tr><td>";

                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='play[]' class='chk_boxes1' value='" . $row['fldBldgName'] . "'>";
                echo $row['fldBldgName'];

                echo "</td></tr><br/>";
           }
}

    ?>
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="all"]').bind('click', function(){
var status = $(this).is(':checked');
$('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', status);
});
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Uhm. what do you mean for that?

Comment: I mean check your browser console (`F12`) if you have got any error.

Comment: do you want to check all boxes with one click? you might find this jQuery function helpful: http://briancray.com/posts/check-all-jquery-javascript

Comment: @verbumSapienti, yes that's want I want. I tried it but its not working. My checkbox are came from database so its auto generated. Its not manually input in the code.

Comment: that shouldn't matter - the jQuery function selects ALL checkboxes within the named fieldset

Comment: I already try that. here's the code

echo "<fieldset>";
  echo "<input type='checkbox' class='chk_boxes' label='check all'  />check all";
  $all = mysql_query("SELECT fldBldgName FROM tblbuildings");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($all))
     {
   echo "<tr><td>";
   
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='play[]' class='chk_boxes1' value='" . $row['fldBldgName'] . "'>";
   echo $row['fldBldgName'];

   echo "</td></tr><br/>";
     }
     echo "</fieldset>";

Comment: that looks right. are you including the jQuery library in the `<head>` ?

Comment: sorry for late reply @verbumSapienti, yes I already include it in the <head>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look  [checked Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' class='chk_boxes1' name='play[]' value='".$row['fldBldgName']. "' checked>";
```

and why a `<br>` in a table?

EDIT

try this:

```
    echo '<div><input type="checkbox" class="checkall"> Check all</div>';
 $all = mysql_query("SELECT fldBldgName FROM tblbuildings");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($all))
           {

           echo "<div><input type='checkbox' name='play[]' class='chk_boxes1' value='" . $row['fldBldgName']."'>";
           echo $row['fldBldgName'];."</div>";

           }
```

and jQuery function:

```
$(function () {
    $('.checkall').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H37cb/210/

Comment: Do you mean for the table is the fldbldgname?

Comment: no, i say that you can add attribute "checked" in the input checkbox... just replace that line of your code by what i wrote here

Comment: The items I load in the second page are already check because of the ""' checked>";"....

Comment: Not really.. I want is. When I click the "Check All" [checkbox] all items I loaded in the second page will also be checked...then when I unchecked the "Check All" the items will be unchecked also.

Comment: do you need help to implement that code (jsfiddle) in your code?

Comment: kinda... I edit my post... Thats what I do in the code...do you think somethins wrong? cuz its not working to me :(

Comment: @Philistyne Brigid Bellisima  check last edit, should work now

Comment: hey. thank you..I already fix it... i forgot to import the src for scrript :)

Answer (score 0):

Try listening to the `change` event on the `.chk_boxes` element. You should also use `prop` instead of `attr` when working with "binary" properties like `checked':

```
$('.chk_boxes').on('change', function(){
    $('.chk_boxes1').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

You also need to wrap all your `tr`/`td` elements in a `table` element.:

```
<table>
<?php
...
?>
</table>
```

There's no need for `br` elements after a `tr`. `tr` will always start on a new line.

Comment: its still not working. I just remove the <br/>. :( The checkbox are came from the database, the one that I want to check all...

Comment: Javascript doesn't care where the checkboxes came from, it just operates on the DOM.

Comment: did you import jQuery? The import statement needs to be before you call any jQuery functions

Comment: @cfs what do you mean for import/?

Comment: @PhilistyneBrigidBellisima In other words, do you have a `script` tag whose `src` attribute is the jquery library? For example: `<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @cfs, I forgot to insert that code but then you said "import" I remember that I need to insert it in my script.  The code is already working. thanks for the help :)